# Why is mongodb $geoWithin operator so slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I want to find geopoints within a specific square in a collection of 75 million documents.

This query takes forever:
`db.tracks.count({"loc":{"$geoWithin":{"$box":[[9.27225895239,41.58687259712],[9.28436304761,41.59586540288]]}}})`

When I replace the query by `{ nLon: { $gt: long2, $lt: long1 }, nLat: { $gt: lat2, $lt: lat1 }` it takes only seconds.

Here's an example document:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55d5d8555df7f55addd16e46"),
  "nLon" : 2,
  "nLat" : 48,
  "loc" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
      2,
      48
    ]
  }
}
```

There are two indexes for latitude / longitude, and a 2dsphere index for `loc`:

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
    "loc" : "2dsphere"
  },
  "name" : "loc_2dsphere",
  "ns" : "locate.tracks",
  "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
}
```

Both queries end up giving exactly the same result: ~4000

Am I missing something? or 2dsphere index is just bad for squares

```
mongod --version
db version v3.0.4
```

Comment: You are likely missing a ["geospatial index"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/applications/geospatial-indexes/), which will make things a whole lot faster in general. The [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) operator does not "require" this, but it works a whole lot better when one is available to be used.

Comment: Also please try and be professional and avoid ["textspeak"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Textspeak)

Comment: @BlakesSeven the 2dsphere I use is actually a geospatial index used for the `$geoWithin` operator

Comment: Well since you only just added that then you should not pretend that your question included it originally. How about 'adding some more detail' like the `.explain()` output from your present query. And talking about how much data you are actually searching and on and  what architecture? How much RAM? Is is sharded? So many things that are not explained in what you are asking.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I removed the other indexes from my question to make it clearer. Using `explain` isn't part of the question to me it's the answer. It reveals that the index wasn't used. If I replace the `$box` by a `$centerSphere` it works!